# Jackson JSON Formatter changes field names with is-Prefix in Spring

Tags: json, spring

I have an JPA Entity class, which will be rendered as JSON.
My issue is that the JSON Formatter somehow rename fields that has a prefix `is`. In this example the field `isMale` will be changed to `male`.

This is my class

```
// this is kotlin code
@Entity
class RegistrationRequest(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        var id: Long,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var firstname: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var lastname: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var isMale: Boolean,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var church: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var language: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var email: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var address: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var country: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var phone: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var jobIsFulltimeStudent: Boolean,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var jobIsTrainee: Boolean,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var jobIsUnemployed: Boolean,

        var comment: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var eventCode: String,


        @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
        var insertDate: Date,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        var isDeleted: Boolean = false

){
        @PrePersist
        protected fun onCreate() {
                insertDate = Date()
        }
}
```

This is an example of generated output

```
{
  "id": 16,
  "firstname": "Bob",
  "lastname": "Marley",
  "church": "xyz",
  "language": "de",
  "email": "local@host.com",
  "address": "Exampleway 23, 8000 Zurich",
  "country": "Switzerland",
  "phone": "012323434",
  "jobIsFulltimeStudent": false,
  "jobIsTrainee": true,
  "jobIsUnemployed": true,
  "comment": "test",
  "eventCode": "NL17",
  "insertDate": 1495204099746,
  "male": false,
  "deleted": false
}
```

If I try to use the annotation `@JsonProperty("jsonFieldName")` then I receive this exception:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1495192430037,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
  "path": "/registrations"
}
```

any ideas how i can keep my fieldnames?

Comment: For once, it's not a bug, it is a feature. But then, `@JsonProperty("male")` is supposed to do exactly what you expected and the error you get does not seem linked with the matter. Content-type not supported somewhat hints to your serialisation layer returning something else than json.

Comment: It can not be because of the serialisation layer. I'm using postman for testing and I'm using the same data for the testing.
https://pastebin.com/XrzAk7Pr

Comment: You mean that if you remove the `@JsonProperty`, the service works but with bad property names, and if you add it (and only the annotation), you get a `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` ? It seems really weird. Is your field name not in UTF-8 ?

Comment: Thats correct. The property name is @JsonProperty("isMale")